# Create Constant Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, var, setcookie

The situation is the next: We have a site that have a lot of domains:.pl,de,com,se... This domeins are only on home page and landing pages. After you make search it is redirecting it on .com domain. So all domains become COM. I need something to create in Google Tag Manager that will remember the first domain (pl,de,com,se and annother) and will hold that information for all the path. So if I will have such information I could exactly indicate to my Adwords tracking codes which code has to fire. I am working with cookies in Google Tag Manager. How to create the cookie that will change only in the situation when the tag with the cookie will fire. I need the cookie that holds the information from one page - not changing with the new page. The code I use is:

```
<script>  
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
createCookie("DomainCookie",{{Page URL}})
```

`</script>`

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Tag with cookie will fire? What tag?

Comment: @somethinghere Sorry for my language it is not my native :( The situation is the next: We have a site that have a lot of domains:.pl,de,com,se... This domeins are only on home page and landing pages. After you make search it is redirecting it on .com domain. So all domains become COM. I need something to create in Google Tag Manager that will remember the first domain (pl,de,com,se and annother) and will hold that information for all the path. So if I will have such information I could exactly indicate to my Adwords tracking codes which code has to fire.

Comment: Hi, the comment explanation is actually a lot better and describes the specific problem very well and I assume will attract more people to try and help you solve this!